# Trying to reverse engineer a Teradata view in ERwin

Tags: teradata, erwin

I am a newbie to Teradata . I am trying to create a DDL script file for a few tables and a view so I can reverse engineer them into Erwin to integrate them into an existing model. I don't have access to the schema with the underlying table for the view. I have  created a volatile table based on the view with the following :

```
    CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE Temp1 AS
    (
    SELECT * FROM databasename.viewname SAMPLE 100
    ) WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Then:

```
    SHOW TABLE Temp1;
```

This shows me the DDL of the view. How do I edit/prepare the script so I can integrate it into an Erwin model or can I?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Do you just wants the column of the view or also where it's data come from? In the second case, you'd better use "SHOW VIEW databasename.viewname".

Comment: I don't know much about Erwin, but you should be able to reverse engineer a table you don't have access to.  Access to metadata is completely different from access to the contents of tables.

Comment: Thank you Insac and Andrew for your responses. I have now resolved this by creating a script file and reverse engineering it in ERwin. what i also learned after getting an error message a few times is that ERwin doesn't support the 'DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO' clause so it has to be removed from the DDL.